# in python, I have 100 page's link and want to save them as html

Tags: python

100 page's links inside (links.txt)
This is the code I have so far (it is save only one page) but the part of saving all the 99 pages is missing

```
import requests
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
   
with open('links.txt', 'r') as links:
    for link in links:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        webContent = response.read()
        f = open('obo-t17800628-33.html', 'wb')
        f.write(webContent)
        f.close
```

Comment: You are oepning and closing the file each time in the for loop. Instead do you want to try and open it in append mode?

Comment: Read this carefully, one line at a time (or, better yet, step through it in a debugger). Is it _really_ just saving one page, or is it really saving _every_ page? Why do you only end up with one file at the end? Asked differently, do you see the _first_ or the _last_ page in your list of links get saved to your file? Why might that be?

Comment: Here in Stack Overflow, there is no need to put "Solved" and other such comments in the question. People can see the answers and the green checkmark indicates which one solved your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers the question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the files different names as you loop:

```python
import requests
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
   
with open('links.txt', 'r') as links:
    for idx, link in enumerate(links):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        webContent = response.read()
        with open('obo-t17800628-33.html' + str(idx), 'wb') as fout:
            fout.write(webContent)
```

This will append a number to the end of each file name.

Comment: wouldn't that create `html0`, `html1` ... instead.

Comment: it will put the content from the link in the first line of `links.txt` in `obo-t17800628-33.html0`, and the content from the second line in `obo-t17800628-33.html1`, etc.... I have no idea what `obo-t17800628-33.html` means, but at least this will accomplish the task of saving each link in a separate file.

Comment: if the file extension really matters, just replace `'obo-t17800628-33.html' + str(idx)` with `str(idx) + 'obo-t17800628-33.html'` to prefix the file names instead.

Comment: opening a file with html0 , html1, .... may result in an error. Instead oepning it in append mode and writing into the file will be a better option

Comment: What error could this produce that would be avoided by using append mode? Sure, this will truncate the files if they exist, so I am making an assumption in that regard. But if I append, that assumes that concatenating the new data onto whatever was in the file already will produce a valid output. There is a lot we don't know, so either way we make assumptions. I'd leave it for OP to decide which is best for this particular use case.